# Ввод текста от пользователя и его поиск в текстовом файле

Tags: java

Только начал изучать Java. Помогите разобраться. Создал примитивный код, который принимает от пользователя строку, заносит ее в массив и разделяет на слова. Как теперь любое слово из этого массива проверить есть ли оно в определенном текстовом файле? Достаточно простой конструкции, лишь бы понять принцип. Если слово нашлось "Ура, нашел", если нет "Слово не найдено". Спасибо.

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import java.io.Serializable;

@ManagedBean(name="user")
@SessionScoped
public class UserTextBean implements Serializable {

public String txt;
public String txtend;

public String getTxtend() {
    txtend = txt.substring(0, 30);
    String[] output = txtend.split(" ");
    return output[1];
}

public void setTxtend(String txtend) {
    this.txtend = txtend;
}

public String getTxt() {
    return txt;
}

public void setTxt(String txt){
    this.txt = txt;
}

}
```

Comment: Открываете файл, загружаете его содержимое в `String`, далее используете `String.substring(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class someClass{

    public static final String content;
    String words[] = SomeClass2.getWords();  //Какой-то класс со статическим методом выдающим массив слов из введенного пользователем предложения

    public someClass(){
        try{
            content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("url")));
        }catch(IOException e){}

    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        boolean isExists = false;
        isExists = content.insexOf(words[индекс слова]);
        if(isExists) System.out.println("Найдено совпадение");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Возможно, это подойдёт:

```
try {
    String text = "";
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("D:/Data/prototype.txt");
    //Открываем поток для вычисления условия
    BufferedReader counter = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
    //Открываем поток для чтения файла
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
    while (counter.readLine() != null) {
        text += br.readLine();//считываем текст
    }
    if (text.contains("TestData")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ура, нашёл!");
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Слово не найдено.");
    }
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```